# LINQ QUERY PROBLEM

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I want an equivalent **linq to object** query for the below sql query

```
SELECT SUM(AMOUNT)
FROM ACCOUNTS a
INNER JOIN  DETAIL d ON a.CODE = d.CODE
INNER JOIN  ACCENTRIES e ON d.EID= e.EID and e.EDATE > '1/1/2000'
GROUP BY d.CODE
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is correct.  Not tested, though.

```
from a in ACCOUNTS 
     join ed in ENTRIESDETAIL on a.ACODE equals ed.ACODE
     join e in ENTRIES on e.EID equals ed.EID
     where e.EDATE > DateTime.Parse("1/1/1990")
     group ed by ed.ACODE into g
     select new { g.Group.Sum(s => s.EDAMOUNT) };
```